# How to resolve error message "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" for data density plot; Diff function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, ggmap, stat-density2d

I am having some trouble trying to plot a density map for crime in my city. I'm using the two-dimensional kernel density estimation through the `stat_density2d()` function. No matter what I change and/or rearrange, I am continually receiving the error message

> Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

I ran the `str` function to check the structure; Lon(gitude) was being read as a character.

```
OakTownMap +
  stat_density2d(aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = ..level.. ,alpha=..level..), bins = 10, geom ="polygon", data = Non_Violent_Crime) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "black", high = "red")+
  ggtitle("Map of Non-Violent Crime Density in Oakland ")
```

I'm truly lost and a little frustrated because I'm sure this requires a very simple adjustment to placement of lon and lat arguments or change in function(?). Should I just change lon from char to num?

[image: str return image]

Comment: If longitude is being read as a character, have you tried `as.numeric(lon)` ?

Comment: Do you mean `ggplot(OakTownMap) +` in the first code line?

Comment: @RuiBarradas no, I tried it with a different dataset and coordinate points and it worked just fine.

Comment: @BrianFisher no I have not. I will try it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot it looks like you need to coerce lon into a numeric vector.  try `Non_Violent_Crimes$lon <- as.numeric(Non_Violent_Crimes$lon)` before you add it to ggplot.  alternatively, when you add the geometry, change "x=lon" into "x=as.numeric(lon)".  This directly addresses the error you are receiving.

Comment: Thank you! While this does address the error, however, no geometry were plotted over the map. 

The code runs, but nothing gets plotted. Should I make changes to the structure of the entire dataset?

Comment: @scarceabundance We probably need to see a bit more of the objects involved.  I'm assuming that OakTownMap is a ggplot object that is in the same coordinate system you are trying to plot to. Can you provide more information.  You might try adding the density plot to a blank map.  Further, check your longitude values and make sure they have a reasonable level of precision - the screen shot only shows degrees, which would place your points 20km east of Oakland.

Comment: Working on that now. Thanks again!

Comment: The dataset had mislabeled the longitude and latitude columns, so they were the opposite of precise. The code is fully functional. Thanks again, Brian